# Enum property is not visible in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, wrapper-class, enum

I have flow which is using Enum property and trying to access in the flow, but for some reason it not showing up,

> Enum Property

[image]

> Wrapper class

[image]

> Not showing up in Flow

[image]

Any clue will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums aren't supported, see [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5)

> Supported data types in an Apex class are Boolean, Integer, Long, Decimal, Double, Date, DateTime, and String. Single values and lists are supported for each data type. Multiple Apex classes can be combined to represent complex web objects.

You'll need to use Strings. See also [enum methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_enum.htm) to enable conversion from string to enum and back

Comment: @croperdy I also found this yesterday.